# Query Audit table to retrieve status change time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

sample data

```
ID    Verification time_created  time_updated 
70000 us           9/12/16 11:25 2/21/17 22:41 
70000 us           9/12/16 11:25  4/3/17 14:20 
70000 us           9/12/16 11:25  4/4/17 22:08 
70000 v            9/12/16 11:25  4/4/17 23:38 
70000 v            9/12/16 11:25 6/22/17 23:52 
70000 v            9/12/16 11:25 10/4/17 19:26
```

I want to extract the time when the status was changed from "us" to "v" denoted by time_updated

I'm using this query right now:

```
select id,verification_status,min(time_updated)
from customer_account_aud
where verification_status='v'
group by id;
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite not sure what you are asking but hope below answer will help you,

```
select id,verification_status,time_updated
from customer_account_aud
where verification_status='v';
```

for [more reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

select (* from customer_account_aud where verification_status='v'
GROUP BY Id, time_updated
ORDER BY (time_updated)). First();